# Using boost::iterator_facade<>

Tags: c++, boost, iterator

I have a linked list structure:

```
struct SomeLinkedList
{
    const char* bar;
    int lots_of_interesting_stuff_in_here;
    DWORD foo;
    SomeLinkedList* pNext;
};
```

**It is part of an existing API and I cannot change it.**

I would like to add iterator support. The `boost::iterator_facade<>` library seemed ideal for the purpose.

```
class SomeIterator
    : public boost::iterator_facade< SomeIterator, 
                                     const SomeLinkedList, 
                                     boost::forward_traversal_tag >
{
public:
    SomeIterator() : node_( NULL ) {};

    explicit SomeIterator( const SomeLinkedList* p ) : node_( p ) {};

private:
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

    void increment() { node_ = node_->pNext; };

    bool equal( SomeIterator const& other ) const { /*some comparison*/; };

    SomeLinkedList const& dereference() const { return *node_; };

    SomeLinkedList const* node_;
}; // class SomeIterator
```

The goal is to be able to use it in standard library functions like `std::for_each`

```
void DoSomething( const SomeLinkedList* node );

SomeLinkedList* my_list = CreateLinkedList();
std::for_each( SomeIterator( my_list ), SomeIterator(), DoSomething );
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting an error saying it's trying to pass the list by value rather than by pointer.

```
error C2664: 'void (const SomeLinkedList *)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const SomeLinkedList' to 'const SomeLinkedList *'
```

How can I change `SomeIterator` to do to get this working correctly?

Thanks,
PaulH

---

Edit:
I've tried this:

```
class SomeIterator
    : public boost::iterator_facade< SomeIterator, 
                                     SomeLinkedList, 
                                     boost::forward_traversal_tag,
                                     SomeLinkedList* >
{
    // ...
```

but I get this complier error:

```
error C2664: 'boost::implicit_cast' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'SomeLinkedList **' to 'boost::detail::operator_arrow_proxy<T>
```

---

Edit 2:

I've tried modifying the dereference type:

```
class SomeIterator
    : public boost::iterator_facade< SomeIterator, 
                                     const SomeLinkedList, 
                                     boost::forward_traversal_tag >
{
    // ...

    const SomeLinkedList* dereference() const { return node_; };
```

but, I get the original error:

```
error C2664: 'void (const SomeLinkedList *)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const SomeLinkedList' to 'const SomeLinkedList *'
```

Comment: Re: the edit. You are still saying that the `value_type` is going to be `SomeLinkedList`. You probably shouldn't need the last parameter at all, since the default should work for that. Also, did you change the return type of the `dereference` member? - But still, since your code base doesn't appear to be particularly stdlib-style, wouldn't it be simpler to write your own foreach for this particular linked list (since I doubt any other stdlib algorithm is going to work well with such a bizarre iterator anyway without serious additional work)?

Comment: @UncleBens - See edit 2. Also, I don't think it would be lots of additional work. Just overload a comparison operator or a binary predicate.

Comment: It seems that you might need `const SomeLinkedList*` both for the `value_type` and the `reference` parameter. Probably some weirdness when it comes to taking references to pointers. - As to additional work: suits you. For me using C-style strings with stdlib is too much work, since it was never designed to support those out of the box.

Comment: @UncleBens - put that in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your iterator is dereferenced, it would return a `const SomeLinkedList&` however your DoSomething function is expecting a `const SomeLinkedList*`. Either alter the iterator to somehow return pointers when dereferenced or alter your DoSomething function.

---

EDIT in response to further discussion:

I haven't actually used boost::iterator_facade myself, but looking at additional code you posted it appears you might not have changed *all* the necessary parts at the same time.

Have you actually tried

```
class SomeIterator
    : public boost::iterator_facade< SomeIterator, 
                                     SomeLinkedList, 
                                     boost::forward_traversal_tag,
                                     SomeLinkedList* >
{
```

**and**

```
const SomeLinkedList* dereference() const { return node_; };
```

together?

Or if that doesn't work, then how about:

```
class SomeIterator
    : public boost::iterator_facade< SomeIterator, 
                                     SomeLinkedList*, 
                                     boost::forward_traversal_tag>
{

const SomeLinkedList* dereference() const { return node_; };
```

Alternatively, as davka suggested in a comment, what about solving the pointer vs reference issue by making a wrapper around DoSomething? Such as:

```
void DoSomethingWrapper( const SomeLinkedList& node )
{
    DoSomething(&node);
}
```

In fact, you could probably even keep the wrapper the same name as the function it wraps and just let overloading rules take care of when the pointer or reference version gets called.

Comment: `DoSomething` is also fixed and cannot be changed. I'd like to know how to modify the `boost::iterator_facade<>` object to work. Ideally, it would behave just like `std::vector< SomeLinkedList* >::const_iterator` (but forward traversal only)

Comment: @PaulH: So did you at least try to change what the iterator dereferences to (also don't forget the template parameters)? IMO, this thing won't look much like regular stdlib iterators, unless it dereferences to the DWORD member anyway. For example, if I want to use `std::find` to find a node with a specific value, why should this not work? Why should the iteration details (that it is a node in an intrusive linked list) get in the way?

Comment: @UncleBens - The idea here is that I **could** use algorithms like `std::find`. Yes, I've tried several things to change what the iterator dereferences to. As yet, I've been unsuccessful in doing that within the framework of `boost::iterator_facade<>`. That is, essentially, what I'm asking in this question.

Comment: could you have some kind of `DoSomethingWraper` that receives `const SomeLinkedList&` and passes its address to the real `DoSomething`? or a functor that does the same?

Answer (score 2):

I have been trying to understand boost::iterator_facade. Searching for a simple example I found this (old) question and the single, accepted answer. I thought I would post the code I needed to get this example to work here, as the existing question and answer never really settle the issue.

In the first instance note that the 2nd parameter to for_each() is an end iterator. I found that a NULL iterator (not sure if this is the right terminology) as used in the original question code works well, but only if you finish off the the incomplete definition of .equal() as follows;

```
bool equal( SomeIterator const& other ) const { return node_ == other.node_; }
```

Apart from that simply changing the definition of the parameter of DoSomething() from ptr to reference, as mentioned in the accepted answer, is the key to getting this to compile and run. I've put some primitive test code below to illustrate.

```
void DoSomething( const SomeLinkedList& node )
{
    std::cout << "DoSomething " << node.foo << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    SomeLinkedList temp[5];
    memset(temp,0,sizeof(temp));
    temp[0].pNext = &temp[1];
    temp[1].pNext = &temp[2];
    temp[2].pNext = &temp[3];
    temp[3].pNext = &temp[4];
    temp[4].pNext = 0;
    temp[0].foo   = 0;
    temp[1].foo   = 1;
    temp[2].foo   = 2;
    temp[3].foo   = 3;
    temp[4].foo   = 4;
    SomeLinkedList* my_list = &temp[0];
    std::for_each( SomeIterator( my_list ), SomeIterator(), DoSomething );
    return 0;
}
```