# How to use boost::iterator_facade to access a legacy linked list

Tags: c++, boost

As part of an attempt to understand how to use boost::iterator_facade I picked up some code from this question [Using boost::iterator_facade<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514457/using-boostiterator-facade/7950007#7950007) and got it running. My completed code follows. My question concerns the end parameter in both the std::for_each and std::find algorithms. I kept the idiom I found in the original code from the original question. Basically it uses a kind of NULL iterator for the end parameter. It works, as long as I define the equal() member in the way shown.

My question is, is this idiom (a NULL iterator (?), maybe there is a real term for this type of iterator that I don't know), well known and good practice. If not, can you recommend an alternative approach.

```
// Element of linked list (legacy code, can't be changed)
struct SomeLinkedList
{
    const char* bar;
    int lots_of_interesting_stuff_in_here;
    long foo;
    SomeLinkedList* pNext;

    // actually I cheated and added this to get std::find working
    bool operator ==( SomeLinkedList const& other ) const { return foo == other.foo; }
};

class SomeIterator
    : public boost::iterator_facade< SomeIterator, 
                                     const SomeLinkedList, 
                                     boost::forward_traversal_tag >
{
public:
    SomeIterator() : node_( NULL ) {};  // used to create end iterators in examples
    explicit SomeIterator( const SomeLinkedList* p ) : node_( p ) {};

private:
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;
    void increment() { node_ = node_->pNext; };
    bool equal( SomeIterator const& other ) const { return node_ == other.node_; }
    SomeLinkedList const& dereference() const { return *node_; };
    SomeLinkedList const* node_;
}; // class SomeIterator

void DoSomething( const SomeLinkedList& node )
{
    std::cout << "DoSomething " << node.foo << "\n";
}

void main()
{
    // Ugly but effective way to create a fake linked list for experiments
    SomeLinkedList temp[3];
    memset(temp,0,sizeof(temp));
    temp[0].pNext = &temp[1];
    temp[1].pNext = &temp[2];
    temp[2].pNext = 0;
    temp[0].foo   = 0;
    temp[1].foo   = 1;
    temp[2].foo   = 2;
    temp[2].bar   = "number 2";
    SomeLinkedList* my_list = &temp[0];

    // DoSomething() for each element in list
    std::for_each( SomeIterator(my_list), /*end*/ SomeIterator(), DoSomething );

    // Find one element in the list
    SomeLinkedList obj;
    obj.foo = 2;
    SomeIterator it = std::find( SomeIterator(my_list),  /*end*/ SomeIterator(), obj );
    std::cout << "found " << it->bar << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I haven't examined your code, but a NULL iterator seems like a very good choice for the `end` iterator since it doesn't point to a valid element.

Comment: This is very common, and known as the 'sentinal iterator'.

Comment: You might want to review your `operator==` in `SomeLinkedList`... it does not compare two lists, but only the head element of the lists. From the comment it seems that you added it to get `std::find(it1,it2,value)` working, if that is the case, you might want to use `std::find_if(it1,it2,functor)` where `functor` is a function object that stores the value you are searching for and will compare the value in the received node in `operator()` with that expected value...

Comment: I was keeping my mods to the original code to a minimum, so I didn't change the type name, but really it is not so much a linked list as an element that can be linked into a linked list. So comparing the element is just what I want, I don't want to compare a whole list. Thanks for your comment though and your answer. I will have to look into functors, they are a bit of a mystery to me at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common approach, and there is no need to change it. If you look in the `iterator` header, you will find `std::istream_iterator<>`, for example, that take a similar approach, the `end` iterator is a special iterator value (`istream_iterator<T>()`) that compares `true` to any iterator that has completed the iteration, regardless of the input stream from which it was initialized.